# Hackerrank python stdin and stdout

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I am still trying to figure out python by myself I've been trying to solve Day 6 problem of hackerrank. Below is my approach to the problem, it is asking me to print the output in stdin and stdout and mine doesn't seem to work. Also, this code works on jupyter notebook giving me a right output, but the output is (hcekr, rnak) in this format without any spaces how do I enter space between these without changing my code? This is the link to the problem. I'd appreciate your help!
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem

```py
import sys 
import os
import random
import re
import math
def numbers():
    S=x.split()[0]
    for idx, ele in enumerate(S):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            print(ele,end='')
    for idx, ele in enumerate(S):
        if idx %2 != 0:
            print(ele,end='')
    N=x.split()[1]
    for idx, ele in enumerate(N):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            print(ele,end='')
    for idx, ele in enumerate(N):
        if idx %2 != 0:
            print(ele,end='')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=str(input().strip())
    print(numbers)
```

I have tried changing the position of `if__name__='__main__'` to the very top of the code. And I've tried returning numbers instead of `print(numbers)` but it doesn't give me an output.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, the below lines cause that you'll not have good results:

> ```py
> print(numbers) # numbers doesn't return anything that you want to print!
> ```

and

> ```py
> def numbers(): # you should pass x to your function
> ```

You just need to change your `numbers()` and `main()` functions as below:

```py
def numbers(x):
    S=x.split()[0]
    for idx, ele in enumerate(S):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            print(ele,end='')
    for idx, ele in enumerate(S):
        if idx %2 != 0:
            print(ele,end='')
    N=x.split()[1]
    for idx, ele in enumerate(N):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            print(ele,end='')
    for idx, ele in enumerate(N):
        if idx %2 != 0:
            print(ele,end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=str(input().strip())
    numbers(x)
```

Comment: And the reason it works in the jupyter notebook, is because the variable x is in scope for the cell in your notebook.

Comment: It it still not giving me an output :( It is just giving the input for the output. It works on notebook. :((

Comment: This is impossible, you are probably wrong somewhere else, although it is not very professional, I have put a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkN7o.png) of the execution of this piece of code in a regular Python terminal for you.